# What's the purpose of "false || false" in this source?

Tags: android

I was reading through some of the Android source and found a line that I can't explain.

See AssetManager.java in the [Android Source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/content/res/AssetManager.java). Near the top is a line that seems to be related to enabling/disabling verbose logging.

```
private static final boolean localLOGV = false || false;
```

What's the purpose of `false || false` here?

Comment: I would guess that this code is partly auto-generated, and these `false`s were originally something else.

Comment: @Thomas no. The AOSP project is open-source meaning the code linked is not decompiled.

Comment: @Zoe Google has a system that synchronizes open-source code with their internal codebase two-way, scrubbing internal parts: https://github.com/google/moe

Comment: @Thomas that makes a reasonable amount of sense. There's no logic to the double 'false' now, but it may just be an artifact of some real logic getting scrubbed.